# How to set tkinter Message border

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried all ways to set tkinter message widget border, but still receive any effect. I wonder if it does not have a border attribute? But I can set label and Text border using the same code. Here is my code snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
message = Message(frame, text="hello world", width=200)
message.config(fg="red", borderwidth=100, highlightcolor="green")
frame.pack()
message.pack()

root.minsize(300, 200)
root.mainloop()
```

this's result:

[image: result without green border]

OS Version:OS X 10.11.4

Python version: 3.52

Comment: doesn't have a `border` attribute, but does have `borderwidth` http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/message.htm#Tkinter.Message.config-method, try `borderwidth=200`

Comment: make no sense, i have already tried such way

Comment: What makes no sense? It says 'borderwidth= Border width. Default value is 2. (borderWidth/BorderWidth)' I tried it in your code and I got such a border

Comment: I have update my code and you can see the result on my computer.

Comment: yes that `Border` looks like it's `100` width, now change and compare it to `200`, you don't see twice `(2*(100))` the width surrounding the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the borderwidth correctly. The issue is that you can't see the changes you are implementing, until your add `background` colour and change the `relief` of the `Frame` and `Message` widget. Now try changing the borderwidths with this revised code, and I trust you get the "gotcha" moment.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, background='yellow', borderwidth=20, relief=RAISED)
message = Message(frame, text="hello world", width=200)
message.config(fg="red", borderwidth=50, highlightcolor="green",
               background='light blue', relief=SUNKEN)
frame.pack()
message.pack()

root.minsize(300, 200)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: result]